# ai.djl.pytorch.zoo.PtZooProvider not found

Tags: java, deep-learning

i am testing the framework djl https://djl.ai/

When i try to load the model  : `ModelZoo.loadModel(criteria)`

I am getting this error :

```
java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: ai.djl.repository.zoo.ZooProvider: Provider ai.djl.pytorch.zoo.PtZooProvider not found
```

```
Criteria<BufferedImage, DetectedObjects> criteria =
                Criteria.builder()
                        .optApplication(Application.CV.OBJECT_DETECTION)
                        .setTypes(BufferedImage.class, DetectedObjects.class)
                        .optFilter("size", "512")
                        .optFilter("backbone", "resnet50")
                        .optFilter("flavor", "v1")
                        .optFilter("dataset", "voc")
                        .optProgress(new ProgressBar())
                        .build();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally find a solution. I just add this to my maven pom.xml file

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ai.djl.pytorch</groupId>
        <artifactId>pytorch-native-auto</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are using master branch. The latest master branch should have fixed this issue. PyTorch support is not officially supported (will be released by early April). You can try stable release by checkout v0.3.0.